# Получить товары по значению свойства

Tags: php, битрикс

Доброго времени суток.

Установил у товаров свойство с названием PREORDER с типом список, и дал ему значение по умолчанию "Не установлено" и второе значение "Да".

Мне нужно получить товары только те у которых в свойство "PREORDER", выбрано "Да".

Пытаюсь так как в документации указано:

```
   $iblock_id =163;
   $iblock_section_id = 11844;
   $arF = ["IBLOCK_ID" => $iblock_id, "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => 
   $iblock_section_id, "PROPERTY_PREORDER.VALUE_ENUM" => "Да"];
   $arSelect = Array();
   $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(),$arF,false, false, $arSelect);
   while($arRes = $res->Fetch()){
      var_dump($arRes);

   }`
```

Но в arRes попадают абсолютно все товары, т.е. у которых в поле Предзаказ нет значения "Да"

Коллеги пожалуйста подскажите как правильно сделать что бы добиться нужно результат?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен.

Решение:

```
$iblock_id =163;
$iblock_section_id = 11844;
$arF = ["IBLOCK_ID" => $iblock_id, "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => 
$iblock_section_id, "PROPERTY_PREORDER_VALUE" => "Да"];
$arSelect = Array();
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(),$arF,false, false, $arSelect);
while($arRes = $res->Fetch()){
var_dump($arRes);

}
```

Нужно вместо "PROPERTY_PREORDER.VALUE_ENUM" прописать "PROPERTY_PREORDER_VALUE"